# Popup window in Xamarin forms is fading out quickly after invoked (Rg.Plugin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create my first Xamarin forms app. This is my first app using C#, And my first Xamarin app, so I ran with the template that gives me the "burger menu" when I created the project in Visual Studio 2019. I found quick guide on youtube that used Rg.Plugins to invoke the popup. I tried doing the same, And I can see it does work, sort of, since the pop-up page is being rendered using a fade in animation. As soon as it has been rendered, it disapears, And the underlying page is being "grayed out", so it seems like it's active, but I simply can't see it.
My guess is that it has something to do with how my other elements is being drawn or because I used the burger menu template? If anyone have an idea about what's going on, I would be glad :)
I have been using the iOS Simulator to test out the app.

Heres XAML for the page invoking the pop-up:

"Frontpage" that invokes on "Clicked="PopupCPR_clicked":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EWSMonitor.Views.Monitorering"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EWSMonitor.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MonitoreringModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#2a2b2b</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <BoxView Color="{StaticResource Primary}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>


        
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="100" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10" WidthRequest="200">
                <Label TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Text="Indtast patient ID (CPR) eller klik på &quot;Monitorer uden patient identifikation&quot;." FontSize="20"/>
                <Label TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Text="Du kan vælge at scanne patientens armbånd eller indtast CPR nummer manuelt! Benyt altid en scanner hvor det er muligt!" FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Label TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" FontSize="12" Padding="0,24,0,0">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <FormattedString.Spans>
                                <Span Text="Fremsøg patient: "/>
                                <!-- <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/> -->
                            </FormattedString.Spans>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>

                
                
                
                
                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Command="{Binding OpenWebCommand}"-->
                    <Button Margin="1,1,1,1" x:Name="PopupCPR" Text="Indtast CPR"
                        Clicked="PopupCPR_clicked"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        CornerRadius="5" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Button Margin="1,1,1,1" Text="Monitorer uden patientidentifikation"
                        Command="{Binding OpenWebCommand}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        CornerRadius="5" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                    
                    

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The xaml.cs file:

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace EWSMonitor.Views
{
    public partial class Monitorering : ContentPage
    {
        public Monitorering()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private PopupCPR _PopupCPR;
        private async void PopupCPR_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _PopupCPR = new PopupCPR();
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(_PopupCPR);
           
            
        }

    }
}
```

Then the popup page xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="EWSMonitor.Views.PopupCPR"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EWSMonitor.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
            <Label Text="Dette er et fedt pop-up vindue" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Test Entry"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               BindingContext="{x:Reference Switch}"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsToggled}"
                               PlaceholderColor="Silver"
                               Keyboard="Email"
                               TextColor="Gray"></Entry>
                        <Switch IsToggled="True" x:Name="Switch"></Switch>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <ActivityIndicator Color="Gray" IsRunning="True"></ActivityIndicator>
                    <Slider Value="0.4" x:Name="Slider"></Slider>
                    <ProgressBar BindingContext="{x:Reference Slider}" Progress="{Binding Path=Value}"></ProgressBar>
                    <Button Text="Close" TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Clicked="OnClose"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            
        </StackLayout>
        
        
    </StackLayout>

    <!--  <ContentView x:Name="popupCPRVindue" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Padding="10,0" IsVisible="true" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Hejsa" />
            <Button Text="Luk" TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Clicked="OnClose"></Button>

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentView>
    -->
<!--
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <Label
            Text="Dette er en stor fed TEST" TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}"/>
        <Button Text="Luk" TextColor="{StaticResource Sekundær}" Clicked="OnClose"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    
    -->
</pages:PopupPage>
```

And the xaml.cs for the popup page:

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace EWSMonitor.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PopupCPR : PopupPage
    {
        public PopupCPR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(0, 5);
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return Content.FadeTo(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture where it possible to see it fade in, before it just disappears:

[Popup before it dissapears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9dav.png)

Comment: `Content.FadeTo(0, 5);` - this sets the Opacity to 0

Comment: I'm an Idiot. Thank you. Ofc - this works!

Comment: @Jason You can post an answer, if you want me to promote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are explicitly setting the `Opacity` to 0

```
Content.FadeTo(0, 5);
```